# How to pass parameter to kendo template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-template

I have this code:

```
var columns = [];

$.each(actions, function (idx, action) {
    actionColumn = { 
        template: '#if (selfActions[i].name === "' + action.name + '"){ # <input type="checkbox" /> some text   # } # '
    }   
    columns.push(actionColumn);
});

 $("#myId").kendoTreeList({
    //...
    columns: columns
});
```

And I want to convert to template such as:

```
<script id="rowLeaveTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
        if (selfActions[i].name === '???action.name???' ){#
            <input type="checkbox" />  some text
        # }  # 
</script>
```

How can I pass parameter `action.name` to template to replace `'???action.name???'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
actionColumn = { 
    template: function(dataItem) {
        return kendo.template($("#rowLeaveTemplate").html())({ actionName:action.name });
    }
}
```

and kendo template itself:

```
<script id="rowLeaveTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # if (selfActions[i].name === actionName ){#
        <input type="checkbox" />  some text
    # }  # 
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks @Gene, however when passing `action.name` as parameter, it overrides other parameter such as `selfActions`, how can I pass it as well?

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak is `selfActions` a global variable? same index `i` should be too.

Comment: it is in datasource, thanks for awesome answers. One more question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34382724/492258), thanks again