# Is it possible have this code equivalent code in kendo external template

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-template

I have [this dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@moguzalp/ewUjA) with its inline template

```
  var actionName = 'read';
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      columns: [
        { field: "name" },
        { field: "age" }
      ],
      dataSource: [
        { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30, read: true, actionName: actionName }
      ],
      detailTemplate: "<div> #:" + actionName  +"# </div>"
    });
```

and [this dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@moguzalp/aliLe) with its external template:

```
<script id="detailTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        #: actionName #
</script> 


var actionName = 'read';
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
{ name: "Jane Doe", age: 30, read: true, actionName: actionName }
  ],
  detailTemplate: function(dataItem){ 
    return kendo.template($("#detailTemplate").html())(dataItem);
  }
});
```

In first one `detailTemplate: "<div> #:" + actionName  +"# </div>"` I can render value: `true` however in second one wiht `#: actionName #` I can render `read`.

So my question how can I render to value `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametr (which you named) *dataItem* takes over data from current row. Then you need to write property which you want to render. *dataItem* is valid for whole template.

```
<script id="detailTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    #: read #
</script>
```

and

```
detailTemplate: function(dataItem){ 
    return kendo.template($("#detailTemplate").html())(dataItem);
}
```

should be enough.

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/IMipA/2)

Parameter of function in detailTemplate will contains all properties from object in row (even not visible as column). So if you will do some special calculations or something you can do it in detailtemplate function and create new property which will be accesible by name in template.

[Dojo example 2](http://dojo.telerik.com/IMipA/3)

Edit:
If you want run (let's say) some command, which is in string you have to use [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function. This function will execute the text. It means if you will use some functuion name as eval parameter, this function will be executed.

[Dojo example 3](http://dojo.telerik.com/IMipA/4)

Yet, I dare to quote one important paragrapg from this site: [eval - mozila developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

> **Don't use eval needlessly!**
>
> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed with the privileges of the caller. If
> you run eval() with a string that could be affected by a malicious
> party, you may end up running malicious code on the user's machine
> with the permissions of your webpage / extension. More importantly,
> third party code can see the scope in which eval() was invoked, which
> can lead to possible attacks in ways to which the similar Function is
> not susceptible.
>
> eval() is also generally slower than the alternatives, since it has to
> invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized
> by modern JS engines.
>
> There are safer (and faster!) alternatives to eval() for common
> use-cases.

Comment: Hi Ademar, actually what I need is `#: read #` by parameter, not hard coded

Comment: Bingo, that's what I am looking for